# checking sendmail status as NON root user

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, sendmail, init.d

I am in the process of converting to CentOS 6.5 from 5.5 and need a way to check if sendmail is on or not.  For reasons I don't want to go through, I need to be able to check if sendmail is ON as a NON root user.  In CentOS 5.5, I could use `/sbin/service sendmail status` running as a non root user.  In CentOS 6.5, security is a bit tighter and new code was added to the `/etc/init.d/sendmail` script:

```
# Check that we're a privileged user
[ `id -u` = 0 ] || exit 4
```

The sendmail script uses the following code to check it's status:

```
status)
   echo -n sendmail; status -p /var/run/sendmail.pid -l sendmail
   RETVAL=$?
   echo -n sm-client; status -p /var/run/sm-client.pid -l sm-client
   [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && RETVAL=$?
  ;;
```

In the beginning of the sendmail script the `functions` library is source so `status()` can be called in the `functions` script

```
 # Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

As root, you would typically see this when running `/sbin/service sendmail status`:

```
sendmail (pid  1107) is running...
sm-client (pid  1115) is running...
```

When running as a NON root user I receive `return code 4`

What I have tried so far is checking `/var/run/sendmail.pid` to get the process ID, then I check to see if there is there is and entry in `/proc` for the pid.  For example,

As a NON root user:

```
cat /var/run/sendmail.pid - Get the pid

1107
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bd -q3600s
```

Then I check `/proc/1107/status`:

```
Name:   sendmail
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   1107
Pid:    1107
PPid:   1
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    0       0       0       0
Gid:    0       51      51      51
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 32
Groups: 51
VmPeak:    12844 kB
VmSize:    12840 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:      2020 kB
VmRSS:      2020 kB
VmData:     1176 kB
VmStk:       208 kB
VmExe:       824 kB
VmLib:     10156 kB
VmPTE:        44 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        1
SigQ:   0/3865
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000001006
SigCgt: 0000000180016201
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: ffffffffffffffff
CapEff: ffffffffffffffff
CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
Cpus_allowed:   1
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Mems_allowed:   1
Mems_allowed_list:      0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        560
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     2
```

If `/proc/<pid>` doesn't exist, I know the service is not on.. This method seems to work, but I don't trust it completely and would rather use `/sbin/service sendmail status`.

Any ideas on the best way to check if sendmail service is running as a NON root user??